# Match codes from xml file to string literals in txt file in python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to match xml enumerations to corresponding string literals in python. The xml file and txt file are below.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xs:schema id="Enumerations" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><xs:simpleType name="TypeMakeModelCode"><xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="AUTO-AC-300" />
<xs:enumeration value="AUTO-ACAD-BEA" />
<xs:enumeration value="AUTO-ACAD-CAN" />
<xs:enumeration value="AUTO-ACAD-INV" />
<xs:enumeration value="AUTO-ACUR-ATL" />
<xs:enumeration value="AUTO-ACUR-CL" />
<xs:enumeration value="AUTO-ACUR-CSX" />
<xs:enumeration value="AUTO-ACUR-EL" />
<xs:enumeration value="AUTO-ACUR-ILX" />
<xs:enumeration value="AUTO-ACUR-INT" />
</xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:schema>
```

txt file

```
VEHICLE CODE      VEHICLE LITERAL
__________________________________________________

AUTO-AC-300        A C (GREAT BRITIAN) 3000 ME
AUTO-ACAD-BEA      ACADIAN (GM OF CANADA) BEAUMONT SERIES
AUTO-ACAD-CAN      ACADIAN (GM OF CANADA) CANSO SERIES
AUTO-ACAD-INV      ACADIAN (GM OF CANADA) INVADER SERIES
AUTO-ACUR-ATL      ACURA TL
AUTO-ACUR-CL       ACURA CL
AUTO-ACUR-CSX      ACURA CSX
AUTO-ACUR-EL       ACURA EL
AUTO-ACUR-ILX      ACURA NULL
AUTO-ACUR-INT      ACURA INTEGRA
```

I haven't tried anything yet as I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what you asked for. What do you expect? How should the result look like, a modified xml? Stackoverflow is a question and answer platform, not free coding generator from others.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to match the two files?  You can get the data from second file using Powershell  with regex: $filename = 'c:\temp\test1.txt'
(Get-content $filename | select-object -skip 3) -match '^(?<code>[^\s]+)\s+(?<litteral>.*$)'

Comment: It is not clear what do you try to get.. please explain

Comment: Sorry this is my fist time trying to actually make a post asking for help. Normally I can get by with google. So I would like in python to be able to have the code such as AUTO-ACUR-ATL be a key in a python dictionary and the literal ACURA TL be saved as the value.

Comment: You mean you are trying to generate Python code? It's not at all clear what output you want to produce.

Comment: So are you looking for something like `d = {'AUTO-ACUR-INT':'ACURA INTEGRA'}` ? @KyleHatfield

Comment: @balderman yes exactly like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need the xml file. Just the text file

```
data = {}
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('AUTO'):
            parts = line.split()
            key = parts[0]
            value = ' '.join(parts[1:])
            data[key] = value
print(data)
```

output

```
{'AUTO-AC-300': 'A C (GREAT BRITIAN) 3000 ME', 'AUTO-ACAD-BEA': 'ACADIAN (GM OF CANADA) BEAUMONT SERIES', 'AUTO-ACAD-CAN': 'ACADIAN (GM OF CANADA) CANSO SERIES', 'AUTO-ACAD-INV': 'ACADIAN (GM OF CANADA) INVADER SERIES', 'AUTO-ACUR-ATL': 'ACURA TL', 'AUTO-ACUR-CL': 'ACURA CL', 'AUTO-ACUR-CSX': 'ACURA CSX', 'AUTO-ACUR-EL': 'ACURA EL', 'AUTO-ACUR-ILX': 'ACURA NULL', 'AUTO-ACUR-INT': 'ACURA INTEGRA'}
```

Comment: What if instead I wanted the dictionary to be like this where the vehicle make is the keys and then the values are another dictionary with the keys being the model and the values being the code for example:
Dictonary:

{'A C (GREAT BRITIAN)': {'3000 ME': 'AUTO-AC-300'}, 'ACADIAN (GM OF CANADA)': {'BEAUMONT SERIES': 'AUTO-ACAD-BEA', 'CANSO SERIES': 'AUTO-ACAD-CAN', 'INVADER SERIES': 'AUTO-ACAD-INV'}, 'ACURA': {'TL': 'AUTO-ACUR-ATL', 'CL': 'AUTO-ACUR-CL', 'CSX': 'AUTO-ACUR-CSX', 'EL': 'AUTO-ACUR-EL', 'NULL': 'AUTO-ACUR-ILX', 'INTEGRA': 'AUTO-ACUR-INT'}}

Comment: Isn't the question about matching XML data and plain text data? If this answer really solves the problem, then the question is misleading.

Comment: "What if instead I wanted..." - Don't move the goalposts. Ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Kyle Hatfield  you have asked a question and I have answered this question.  Please accept the answer if it answer your original question.